# How to deal with GoogleWebLight and cookies when redirecting

Tags: python, cookies, googleweblight

I run Flask on gunicorn with Python3. When someone visits my site I redirect them with a 303 to another page of me and add a cookie with some data.

However Google added googleweblight in Brasil and whenever this is used I don't get the cookie on the second page.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look over here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428 you'll see that Googleweblight specifically doesn't support cookies for the client.

One idea you could use would be to attempt to set a cookie on the initial page load, even something simple like `hasCookies=true`. On the page you redirect to you would then attempt to read that cookie, and if it isn't set then you know you're dealing with a client / browser that doesn't support cookies.  From there on you could instead append a uniqueId that you've generated to the URL for later requests. This uniqueId could be used to look up a session in a database, or wherever you happen to store that information.

The positive side here is that the solution would work for any browser that either doesn't support cookies, or where a user has cookies disabled, not just Googleweblight users.

Hope that helps.